# Xampp launcher does not open window

Tags: .desktop, xampp, launcher

I am creating Xampp desktop launcher on my Linux Mint 19 and I have very interesting problem.

When I run this from terminal:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run &
```

everything works correctly, XAMPP control panel opens.

But when I have launcher (I want to create icon for desktop) with code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start or Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run 
Icon[en_US]=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/network-wired.svg
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Name[en_US]=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment[en_US]=Start or Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

It prompts me for password but the window never opens. I tried various scripts and this one works in launcher:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start or Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=**sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run**
Icon[en_US]=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/network-wired.svg
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=**true**
Name[en_US]=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment[en_US]=Start or Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

XAMPP control panel window opens but also the terminal that started it.

How can I create launcher that only opens the XAMPP control panel window without additional terminal?

Comment: Does your `.desktop` file work as expected if you remove the `&` from the command? Like this: `Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run`

Comment: no it only prompts window for password (as the command with & included) and after typing password nothing happens. I am using Linux Mint 19

Comment: `Exec=` defines an executable, it's not a shell interpreter. Use `sh -c "blabla"`, if you wanna use shell.

Comment: great it works now! I kind of knew that the problem will not be in the command but in the way how linux processes it
Correct code to the desktop launcher is:
`sh -c "pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run"`

Answer (score 2):

Correct code to the desktop launcher:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start or Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=sh -c "pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run"
Icon[en_US]=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/24/network-wired.svg
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Name[en_US]=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment[en_US]=Start or Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

Comment: out of all these questions/answers, i found you, the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [JQL/com.ubuntu.pkexec.xampp.policy](https://gist.github.com/JQL/122553c01aa64553414d1d60a62934eb) on my Ubuntu 19.04 and it works 100%. And of course for Ubuntu Menu Editor use [Ubuntu Alacarte Menu Editor](https://www.lifewire.com/ubuntu-alacarte-menu-editor-2205584).